# Generating a grid of images in windows phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I am on a team that, given a set of images, is trying to create a grid of 2 X 2 images in Windows Phone 8 - similar to what Spotify does when it generates a composite of images of the albums in a playlist:

[image]

The current way we are doing this in our app involves the use of Grids, WriteableBitmaps and Bitmap objects. However, those objects are tied to the UI thread, and we would like to do all image processing in a separate thread without interrupting the UI thread.

My question is: Is there some way to do it without interrupting the UI thread? If this is not possible with the given framework in WP8, are there third party libraries (C# or C++) that would allow us to do this?

Thanks.

P.S. I realize I could deal with byte arrays and memory streams and thus avoid third party libraries, but I would rather not go through that trouble if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDI and GDI+ [are not available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but DirectX and Direct2D are available for Windows Phone 8 Apps.  However, no C# API exists in the .Net BCL, so you will have to use a wrapper like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), which has a WinRT version.

As far as the actual drawing commands, you still end up creating a bitmap, writing to it, closing it and shuffling bytes around.  See the [OfflineImageProcessing application](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Samples/Direct2D1/OfflineImageProcessingApp/Program.cs?r=427997002367ed37e7f09c953cc99fcecc83e76d) for such an example.

Sadly, SharpDX, while extremely helpful, is a very thin wrapper upon the native COM Interfaces, and the complexity of using Direct2D for simple operations can be daunting.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. It looks like this might be useful, but prohibitive because of licensing. I should have clarified that part in my question. Thanks again

Comment: @letsgoyeti, SharpDX is published under the MIT License, which allows for pretty much anything you want as long as you include attribution for the use of the library.  Is there a specific type of license you are looking for? MS-PL and most others are usually far more restrictive.

Comment: D'oh, my bad for reading too quickly. MIT license will work for us just fine. I'll mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at my [windows 8 store example here...](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2012/06/22/comdaybe-image-manipulation-in-windows-8-metro-app/)
This code will also work on windows phone 8 now!
I created an async method ( so it will not block the UI ) that will use 4 images as input and return 1 with the 4 images merged as your example shown above.

How I did it in the example is using one string with 4 url's concatenated together separated by a ;
But how to use the input is up to you...

To create one merged imaged, I'm using the `Blit` method of the `WriteableBitmapEx` library [found here...](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)

Comment: WrieableBitmapEx looks like a great third party library. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"?

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0">
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImgURL}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967560%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Images):

***Image creation***

A Windows Phone OS 7.1 performance optimization worth noting is the option to move image decoding to background threads instead of blocking the UI thread. This can be achieved by setting the CreateOptions attribute to BackgroundCreation. For example:

Comment: fps are definitely higher and it has a lazy loading effect, take a look at www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/winpulse/9a7e5cef-d5e2-4758-a9e0-e55eeda5402e